# Preventing an AjaxToolkit Accordion From Opening

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working on a project where I am using the AJAXToolkit Accordion. What I am trying to achieve is the following. I want to capture the event of when the header of the Accordion has been clicked prevent that relevant section of the Accordion from opening and instead postback to the server to populate a DataGrid within the body section of the Accordion, once the DataGrid is populated then expand the selection that was just prevent from opening. (I know how to fire a postback to the server). I have searched the internet with no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle accordion open event on the [client side (selectedIndexChanging)](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Accordion%20Control%20Reference) and use [PageRequestManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee216365(v=vs.100).aspx) ( js object handling postbacks ) to do postback and get updated grid.

Alternatively you can `OnItemCommand(AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionCommandEventArgs)` event and look for `selectedIndex` command ( not sure with the name though) and trigger databind on grid on the server side.

Comment: Couldn't workout how to get it to work via the OnItemCommand but was able to achieve the desired affect with the selectedIndexChanging. Thanks